# Are 2 SET / WHERE instructions in SQL possible?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I want to write an update query using SQL in Access 2010 that should write me a word into a table depending on a criterion. It looks like this:

```
UPDATE tblFinalOrder AS a 
SET a.Status = "won"
WHERE a.System_Qant = 1
AND 
SET a.Status = "cancelled"
WHERE a.System_Qant = 2;
```

It tells me: missing operator. But is something like this possible? Or do I have to find another solution?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Switch Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379?CorrelationId=fdd847dd-362a-4aae-ade2-43bf96556439&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Please try this:

```
  UPDATE tblFinalOrder 
  SET Status = Switch (
               System_Qant = 1, "won",
               System_Qant = 2, 'cancelled'
  );
```

Comment: I will use this version since I've never used the Switch Function before. Thank you very much, I learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE tblFinalOrder 
SET status = (case when System_Qant = 1 then 'Won'
              when System_Qant = 2 then 'cancelled'
              End)
```